# converting Mongoose returned array to regular JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a `Node.js` App, i want to fetch some data from database via `Mongoose`. i do it like this:

```
Users.find({_id:userID}).exec(function(err, users){

});
```

because `users` is an Array like `Mongoose` object, i cant do this:

```
users.toJSON();
```

this works if i use `findOne` but right now doesn't work. also `users.toObject()` doesn't work and i get this error:

```
object has no method 'toObject'
```

if i use `lean()` in query like this:

```
Users.find({_id:userID}).lean().exec(function(err, users){

});
```

this works but it has other problems. for example, if an array value has no value, instead of showing it like this:

```
myval:[]
```

doesn't show that key/value pair at all!!

What i want is that i have to edit that users result and apparently, its `Mongoose` object and i cant. because of that i have to convert it to a regular `JSON` but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `findOne` instead of `find` and you'll be able to edit your instance.

If you absolutely have to use `find` then know that `users` parameter is the array of user instances, so just loop through them and edit them one by one.

```
Users.find({_id:userID}).exec(function(err, users){
  users.forEach(function(user){
    // edit my user here
  });
});
```